# List Collection object as Method Parameter

Tags: c#, list, collections, methods, invoke

Can anyone explain how the memory allocation is done while invoking a method having list collection as parameter. Since the code snippet below though apparently seems to result same but it is not resulting same.
So I would like to know the difference in both the method call in terms of memory allocation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ListSample
{
    class ListSampleClass   
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> i = new List<int>();
            i.Add(10);
            i.Add(15);
            SampleMethod1(i);
            Console.WriteLine("Result of SampleMethod1:"+i[0]);
            SampleMethod2(i);
            Console.WriteLine("Result of SampleMethod2:" + i[0]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void SampleMethod1(List<int> i)
        {
            List<int> j = new List<int>();
            j.Insert(0,20);
            i = j; 
        }

        public static void SampleMethod2(List<int> i)
        {
            List<int> j = new List<int>();            
            j = i;
            j.Insert(0, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Unless you specify `ref` or `out`, parameters are passed by value. For reference types, that means a *reference* to the object (the `List<int>` in this case) is passed by value.

"Pass by value" means that the *argument* (the expression in the calling statement) is evaluated, and then the resulting value is copied into the *parameter* (the variable listed in the method signature). Any further changes to the parameter, in terms of assigning it a new value, are *not* seen by the caller. (But keep reading...)

That means that in your first method call:

```
public static void SampleMethod1(List<int> i)
{
    List<int> j = new List<int>();
    j.Insert(0,20);
    i = j; 
}
```

you're creating a new list, inserting a value into it, and then copying the reference to that new list to `i` - but that has *no effect at all*. The parameter is effectively just another local variable - a change to the value of the variable itself doesn't affect the caller.

Now compare that with your second method:

```
public static void SampleMethod2(List<int> i)
{
    List<int> j = new List<int>();            
    j = i;
    j.Insert(0, 20);
}
```

This creates a new list and then immediately ignores it, instead assigning the reference to the list passed in (as `i`) to `j`. It then inserts a value into the list. The net result of this method is that a value is inserted into the list. It's equivalent to:

```
public static void SampleMethod2(List<int> i)
{
    i.Insert(0, 20);
}
```

Note that this is *not* changing the value of the parameter. It's making a change to the object that the value of the parameter refers to. This is a *crucial* difference to understand.

I have an article on [parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) and another one on [reference and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) which may help you understand this more.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,if so then shouldn't SampleMethod2() also give me same result as SampleMethod1()?

Comment: @Ardentaj: No - calling `SampleMethod1` does *nothing* to the list that's passed in, because the `Insert` method is called on the list created within the method. `SampleMethod2` will insert the value into the list that is passed in.

Comment: Thanks Jon...I will go through your articles and do you suggest any free memory profilers so that I can seethe memory allocations

Comment: @Ardentaj: I wouldn't start using profilers to be honest. Don't think about implementation details (stacks and heaps etc) - think about the *principles* of what's going on. Eric Lippert's blog has a lot more detail about value types and reference types too.

Comment: It's good to understand the principles but I was curious to know the implementation too :)

Comment: @Ardentaj: Well if you must, at least make sure you understand the principles first. Don't forget that the implementation can change.

Comment: @Ardentaj, if you want to see the implementation, you can [download the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx), or decompile it with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)